# how to install python3 with all it is tools on Redhat RHEL 7 offline mahcine

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, installation, rhel7

I have a Django project that is going to be installed in an RHEL 7 server with no internet access. so I need to include everything locally, starting from python3 source, to pip and setup tools . with every package that the system may need to run python, I have added tons and tons of packages, but still, it gives me error all the time. I'm using this **install.sh** script to achive that :

```sh
#!/bin/bash
cd ./needed_pkgs/
rpm -i build-essentials-2019-3pclos2019.noarch.rpm zlib-1.2.7-18.el7.x86_64.rpm gcc-c++-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64.rpm gcc-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64.rpm cpp-4.8.5-39.el7.x86_64.rpm glibc-devel-2.17-292.el7.x86_64.rpm glibc-headers-2.17-292.el7.x86_64.rpm kernel-headers-3.10.0-1062.el7.x86_64.rpm
command -v python3 >/dev/null 2>&1 || {
  echo >&2 "I require python3 but it's not installed, installing it .";
  cd Python-3.7.5
  make clean
./configure
make
sudo make install
}
cd ../..
#virtualenv --never-download venv
#source venv/bin/activate
for entry in "./pkgs"/*; do
  pip install "$entry"
done
```

After days of trying, and as I was getting close to getting it all working, I got this strange error. at the last step of pip install :

[image]

[image]

And it ends up with a failure in installing python:

[image]

Comment: And, do you have the RPMs for `glibc-headers` and `glibc-dev` installed?

Comment: And please don't post screenshots of code or error messages  -  post text.

Comment: @tink yes, I have both in the rpm commands `glibc-devel-2.17-292.el7.x86_64.rpm glibc-headers-2.17-292.el7.x86_64.rpm`